# How to open my application from browser?

Tags: ios, http

## I am using this one[image]

I am using this ketan11://

But I want to use http:// instead of ketan11://

For Example : If I hit `http://example.com` and URL Schemes -> Item 0 = `http://example.com`

Is it possible ?

So, from that example.com I can open my application.

Any solution then, please help me.

Comment: You want to pass data to your app ??

Comment: No i just want to open my app using http from browser

Comment: Then why don't you hit `ketan11://` in the browser ?

Comment: i want to open my apllication if i am open `http://example.com` in browser.

Comment: One way is to redirect `http://ketan.com` to `ketan11://`, I'm not sure whether this will work or not, you've to try it out.

Comment: please see edit. from that you can understand what I want :(

Comment: For your question `Is it possible?`. I don't know (may be not possible). Just try it and let me know too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52386/discussion-between-ketan-patel-and-inder-kumar-rathore)

Comment: This is probably disallowed by the SDK, considering that fact that if apps were allowed to take over specific URLs the User Experience implications would be tremendously poor.